# iTunes not letting me restore iPhone 6+ from ipsw file?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, restore

The error message I get is "... could not be restored because the firmware is not compatible."

I have tried:

1. Reinstalling iTunes (yes, it's the newest version)
2. Rebooting both my laptop and iPhone multiple times
3. Putting my phone in DFU mode

I get the file from ipsw.me (iPhone7,1_9.3.3_13G34_Restore.ipsw)

iTunes DOES allow me to update my phone to the newest iOS, but I don't want that version - I want 9.3.3

I am out of ideas. Anyone have any? Thanks for any and all help.

Also: currently on iOS 9.0.2 (jailbroken)

UPDATE: According to ipsw.me Apple is still signing the old firmware (9.3.3 and 9.3.2 (https://ipsw.me/signed). So this mustn't be an issue.

Comment: Apple stops signing the old IPSW files after the next OS is unveiled. You may have to upgrade to the newest iOS. There is no way to upgrade with an unsigned IPSW file.

Comment: @bret7600 9.3.3 is still being signed, shouldn't be a problem. I've done exactly this, 9.0.2 jailbroken to 9.3.3 (then jailbreak) without a problem.